# Cron doesn't run after installing Mountain Lion. How can I make them run again?

Tags: macos, cron

My Cron tasks stopped running after I installed Mountain Lion.  How do I get them to run again?

Answer (score 6):

The resolution turned out to be creating the etc/crontab file (e.g., `sudo touch /etc/crontab`).  Apparently, this file was deleted during the installation of Mountain Lion.

Comment: +1 for even having cron around so long after launchd was christened and cron was deprecated.